# Proving that $\lim\limits_{z \rightarrow 1-i} [x+i(2x+y)] = 1+i$

Tags: complex-analysis, limits, proof-verification

I am attempting to prove the following strictly from the definition of limit:

$$\lim\limits_{z \rightarrow 1-i} [x+i(2x+y)] = 1+i$$

In other words, we want to show that $\forall \varepsilon > 0$, $\exists \delta > 0$ such that:

\begin{align} 0 < |(x+iy)-(1-i)| < \delta &\implies |(x+i(2x+y))-(1+i)|<\varepsilon \\\\ &\iff \\\\
0 < |(x-1)+i(y+1)| < \delta &\implies |(x-1)+i(2x+y-1)|<\varepsilon
\end{align}

I observed that we can rewrite the $\varepsilon$-neighborhood as follows:

\begin{align}|(x-1)+i(2x+y-1)| &= |(x-1)+i(2x-2+y+1)| \\
&= |(x-1)+i(2(x-1)+(y+1))| \\
&= |(x-1)(1+2i)+i(y+1)| \\
&< \varepsilon
\end{align}

I am not sure if it means anything that the rewritten $\varepsilon$-neighborhood bears some similarity to the $\delta$-neighborhood (that is, the presence of the $1+2i$ term), but in any case, I am unsure of how to proceed.

Comment: $|x-1| \leq |(x-1)+i(y+1)| < \delta $

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:**

$|x-1| \le |(x-1)+i(y+1)| < \delta $

$|y+1| \le |(x-1)+i(y+1)| < \delta $

then use triangular inequality with $|(x-1)(1+2i)+i(y+1)|$.